# Watson Studio unable to create an empty project by adding new storage

Tags: ibm-watson

A seemingly easy task is really bothering me.  (By the way, I'm using the free version.)

1. I created a "Watson Studio-35" service with location as London. (Based on my profile the system assigned it. I didn't have an option to select it.)
2. The system took me to the "IBM Cloud Pack for Data" section so I can create a project.
3. I selected "Create a Project"/"Create and empty project".
4. In the "New Project" page I entered the Name and Description fields and selected "Add" storage.
5. After creating a new storage, came back to the "New Project" page so I can assign the newly added storage to the project.
6. Even after selecting the Refresh the newly created storage in not being assigned to the New Project.

There is no error whatsoever, and the task is just hanging there. There are no options for me to change, like the location, etc. I deleted the Service and Storage in the Dashboard multiple times and did the same steps as stated above, and always the same result.

Anyone with some knowledge on this issue, kindly put some light on this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem occurred since your Watson Studio and Cloud Object Storage services are not located in the same region so the project could not find the provisioned COS. Please check that in your case, COS also should be provisioned in London.